# iOS jailbreak development without device

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, jailbreak

Is it possible to develop an iOS app which interacts with files outside of that app's *sandbox*, just running on the simulator?

(I don't have the device)

Comment: @Downvoters please don't just downvote at least explain why your downvoting than they can improve there question or know where they have gone wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access the information (files) in others apps yes, it possible. When running on the Simulator you have access to the full content of your hard disk, so all you have to do is write the full path to the file, for example with the following lines I am reading the content of a file that belongs to another app.

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/8ADF930D-576E-4163-ABD2-85A6D92AD676/Documents/test.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Comment: can i access files like "/private/var/root/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db" in simulator?

Comment: no, you can't, this file do not exist in the simulator, remember that you can't make a call from the simulator